# Docker compose gives invalid environment type error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am implementing `bitnami-docker-wordpress` for the first time. These are the configuration I have in my `yml` file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      # - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - MARIADB_USER: wordpress
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    image: 'bitnami/wordpress:latest'
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
```

Now, when I try to run `docker-compose up -d` I am getting following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mariadb.environment contains {"MARIADB_USER": "wordpress"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
services.wordpress.environment contains {"WORDPRESS_DB_HOST": "mariadb:3306"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Can anybody help me solve this configuration?

Thank You.

Comment: either remove the "-" from the environment or update your docker-compose version to support "version: 3.2" 
 
reference: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4763#issuecomment-297509279

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      # - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      MARIADB_USER: wordpress
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MARIADB_DATABASE: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    image: 'bitnami/wordpress:latest'
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
```

The environment parameters are either defined as

```
environment:
  param1:value1
  param2:value2
```

or

```
environment:
  - param1=value1
  - param2=value2
```

Comment: @Vishakha Lall,with above configuration it is not creating any files. can you pls help me

Comment: The environment paratmeter do take an input denoted by **-** but with an **=** sign instead of **:**. **SYNTAX** `- MARIADB_USER=wordpress`

Comment: But when I run docker-compose up -d, This should create a wordpress file right? my case it is not creating any

Comment: @nas which wordpress file are you referring to?

Comment: @VishakhaLall I put another question instead. Sorry to bother you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205516/error-establish-a-database-connection-docker-compose

Answer (score 2):

That error is because you are using the character `-` in environment from wordpress

```
environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

And should be:

```
environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Regards