# Error establish a database connection docker compose

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup `wordpress` with `docker`. I have included my yaml file below. Here I have set my mariadb_database to db_tyre.

When I hit `docker-compose up -d`, it is creating all the required files of wordpress. This is also creating db_tyre database but when I try localhost:8000, it gives me `Error establishing a database connection`.

I have checked the wp-config.php file, it has following lines.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'mariadb:3306');
```

### yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_DATABASE: db_tyre
      MARIADB_USER: wordpress
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: you should change the db-host to `define( 'DB_HOST', 'db:3306')` as the service-name you use in docker-compose

Comment: @invad0r how about DB_NAME and  DB_USER.?

Comment: they should be fine as they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should set update the `HOST` but still, it will not work, as the WordPress DB configuration does not seems correct.

ENV for DB is

```
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_DATABASE: db_tyre
      MARIADB_USER: wordpress
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

so the WordPress DB configuration should be updated and it should be `db_tyre`

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'db_tyre');

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'db:3306');
```

or can try with offical image

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

Comment: With the provided configuration, it doesn't automatically set the wp_config file?

Comment: it should work, but if there is issue then you can try with `docker-compose down`, as the volume keep the database persistent and new password will not effect, is there any issue still?

Comment: Yes same problem

Comment: I tried docker-compose down and i still have same problem